# select recyclerview items with long click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I know there are tons of topics talking about this subject, but I didn't see they talk about it properly. I have a recyclerview which plays the tracks when user clicks on it. I want to implement a function that with long click, the selection operation replaces the playing operation and even checkboxes appear on the side of the items.

this implementation exists in almost every app and it seems easy to implement. but in other topics, they only talk about how to select and deselect items and the problem is, That part is easy.
But how do you actually replace the existing operation when long clicking on an item with selection operation?

my adapter:

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<MusicSample> collection;
private Uri playing;
private Uri chosen;
private OnMusicChange mListener;

public MusicAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MusicSample> collection, OnMusicChange mListener){
    this.context = context;
    this.collection = collection;
    this.mListener = mListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_song_item,parent,false);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    viewHolder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MusicSample currentMusic = collection.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            chosen = currentMusic.getLocation();
            mListener.enable(true);
            MusicController.Controller(context,mListener,currentMusic,collection);
        }
    });
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            holder.title.setText(collection.get(position).getTitle());
            holder.singer.setText(collection.get(position).getSinger());
            holder.coverArt.setImageBitmap(collection.get(position).getCoverArt());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return collection.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ImageView coverArt;
    public TextView title;
    public TextView singer;
    public RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        coverArt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cover_art);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        singer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_singer);
        relativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_layout);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey @Paya, please explain your query with your code

Comment: @piyushpk I will add my code, but it's not about mine. the code I'm adding, says that whenever an item is clicked, a track will start playing. that's what I wrote on onCreateViewHolder. But it should change when the item is long clicked right? I updated my question.

Comment: I think due MediaController/MusicController you are not able to access pre-defined setOnLongClickListener, so you have to implement "View.OnLongClickListener" in your MusicController and manage it manually

Comment: viewHolder.relativeLayout.setOnLongClickListner and else the code will remain same and implement this in your onBindViewHolder method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
  holder.relativeLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            //WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LONG CLICK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Use this in your `onBindViewHolder` method and remove below code form `onCreateViewHolder` and try

```
   viewHolder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MusicSample currentMusic = collection.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        chosen = currentMusic.getLocation();
        mListener.enable(true);
        MusicController.Controller(context,mListener,currentMusic,collection);
    }
});
```

Comment: how does it replace the main function?

Comment: i didn't get your question

Comment: In my app, let's say by default, it plays a song when you click on item. my question was how do I replace the playing function with selection when user holds an item.

Comment: can you share the RecyclerView Adapter class?
So that i will look into it and suggest you.

Comment: i have edited my code check once, this might work for you

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something here... It only works if the user long clicks on items and after long click, if user clicks (normal click) on another item, it will start playing the track right? What I want is that if the user long clicks on let's say item no.1, selects the item no.1 and if user "Clicks" (normal click) on other items, they should be selected as well. "with long click starts and continues with click". I'd appreciate it if you could tell me if I'm missing something here.

Comment: https://bignerdranch.github.io/recyclerview-multiselect/  try this one, i think this is what you want

Comment: thank you so much! this is exactly what I'm looking for. thank you for sticking around and helping me.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the code to your adapter :

```
 holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```